# Remove NTFS encryption from files

Tags: windows-10, ntfs, efs

One of the programs I used, apparently, set up file encryption on my PC. First, I noticed the "Encrypting File System" pop up asking to backup encryption certificate and key, then once I started looking why it would pop up in the first place, I found a certificate present in the user certificate storage with the purpose specified as "Encrypting file system" and "Valid From" a few minutes ago.

Running `cipher /u /n` gave me a list of encrypted files, which allowed me to (hopefully) identify the responsible program and remove it, unfortunately, for some reason it enabled encryption on whole bunch of files that are not related to that program and have paths that start with `C:\Program Files\WindowsApps` and `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Packages` (Windows Store apps, I presume).

I have access to the files, can see their contents, but for some reason I can't seem to remove encryption from them:

```
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.FlightSimulator_xxxxxxxxxxxxx\Settings>cipher /d settings.dat

 Decrypting files in C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.FlightSimulator_xxxxxxxxxxxxx\Settings\

settings.dat        [ERR]
settings.dat: The parameter is incorrect.

0 file(s) [or directorie(s)] within 1 directorie(s) were decrypted.
```

It fails if I run it as Administrator, and even if I run it as SYSTEM with PsExec. Any idea how to decrypt those so I could safely remove the encryption certificate?

Update 1: The "Encrypt contents" checkbox is not set on a folder:
[image: Folder settings screenshot]

It is set on individual files, but trying to remove it produces the same error as `cipher /d` produced:

[image: Error Applying Attributes]

I am the owner of the files:

[image: file ownership]

Comment: Can you provide screenshots of all the relevant Windows that indicates the ACL and permissions for the folder in question?  I assume you have tried to just uncheck the checkbox in the properties for the folder?

Comment: @Ramhound, added more details in the post. The permissions on file are inherited from the parent folder, I set myself as an owner of all files in questions when initially failed to remove encryption.

Comment: [The reason you are having a problem is due to the fact you are dealing with DRM.](https://www.avsim.com/forums/topic/585453-are-msfs-folders-encrypted/)  Why are you masking the folder name?  It's not unique to your system.

Comment: I am not a Windows person, but I am confused as to what NTFS has to do with individual file encryption. To my knowledge NTFS is a file system type and if individual files are being encrypted, that has nothing to do with the file system: The same issue would appear if the file system was not NTFS.

Comment: @Giacomo1968, EFS is a feature of NTFS.

Comment: @Ramhound, like I said, that stuff started yesterday, I have MSFS installed since around it was released. The certificate used for encryption is dated yesterday. It is not MSFS that encrypts files and not only MSFS files are encrypted, those were just on top of the list.

Comment: @n0rd - Did you install Microsoft Flight Simulator yesterday?  Because I found a thread that literally confirms this is normal and is protecting the MSFS files. It seems we don’t have all the necessary information required to answer your question

Comment: “…protecting the MSFS files…” Why would anyone need to “protect” Microsoft Flight Simulator files via encryption?

Comment: @Ramhound, I have MSFS installed for months, there are other files encrypted that are not related to it at all, EFS does not prevent *me* from getting the contents of the file, it prevents everyone one else (without proper certificate). And, EFS is *not* available on Windows Home, which would make it really inconvenient for using in any kind of DRM. Given that, I don't buy the DRM argument. It's just a speculation of some random person on Internet.

Comment: It’s absolutely not speculation on my part

Comment: I was talking about the contents of the forum link you sent...